# Merlin on Emacs (GUI) does not get merlin's configuration provided by dune

Tags: emacs, ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune, merlin

First, please know that I am a beginner with Dune and project management in Ocaml. Nevertheless, I have installed Dune and created a new Dune-project which deals with camlimages library,  graphics, etc. **Project compilation and execution works well** when i do the usual:

- *opam exec dune build*
- *opam exec dune exec ./myexecutable.exe*

**However, I can't use Tuareg Mode in emacs because the latter doesn't seem to find/understand well the dune-project configuration file** standing for the former ".merlin" before dune v2.8 (according to the doc: https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=merlin). That **implies lot of "*unbound modules*" errors** when I try to launch the current .ml into the Tuareg repl.

I've tried to add packages manually with

- *Merlin > Select packages*

but Merlin does not seem to care about this, even though it appears in the merlin configuration file.

---

**Some hypothesis**:

Every time I want to access external "opam-installed" library/packages from dune, I need to launch Dune from Opam in order to access them instead of launching a simple "Dune" command into the shell. I feel the "Opam environment" is not accessible from the "shell environment". Does that play a role in my problem?

---

You could find some relevant information below, which might be useful to understand my problem:

- ***Merlin** > Check **configuration*** without adding packages manually

> Loaded .merlin files: /home/erwan/Bureau/Nextcloud/GIT/Projet_integrateur_L3OPTIM/dev/importimg/dune-project
> Custom buffer settings:
> -packages: none
> -flags: ""
> -extensions: none
> Custom merlin setup: ((env "PATH=/home/erwan/.opam/default/bin") (command . "/home/erwan/.opam/default/bin/ocamlmerlin"))

- **Dune file**

> (executable
> (name importimg)
> (libraries camlimages.core camlimages.png graphics camlimages.graphics))

- **[Snippet of code + Typical error i get from the REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBKy.png)**

- **Tree structure** of my project (as generated by dune)

```html
.
├── _build
│   ├── default
│   │   ├── dune
│   │   ├── dune-project
│   │   ├── image.png
│   │   ├── importimg.exe
│   │   └── importimg.ml
│   └── log
├── dune
├── dune-project
├── image.png
├── #importimg.ml#
└── importimg.ml
```

- **.emacs content**

```
;; Basic .emacs with a good set of defaults, to be used as template for usage
;; with OCaml and OPAM
;;
;; Author: Louis Gesbert <louis.gesbert@ocamlpro.com>
;; Released under CC0

;; Generic, recommended configuration options

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ac-use-fuzzy nil)
 '(backup-directory-alist (quote (("." . "~/.local/share/emacs/backups"))))
 '(compilation-context-lines 2)
 '(compilation-error-screen-columns nil)
 '(compilation-scroll-output t)
 '(compilation-search-path (quote (nil "src")))
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
 '(electric-indent-mode nil)
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil)
 '(line-move-visual t)
 '(next-error-highlight t)
 '(next-error-highlight-no-select t)
 '(next-line-add-newlines nil)
 '(require-final-newline t)
 '(sentence-end-double-space nil)
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(show-trailing-whitespace t)
 '(visible-bell t))

;; ANSI color in compilation buffer
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()
  (toggle-read-only)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (toggle-read-only))
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)

;; Some key bindings

(global-set-key [f3] 'next-match)
(defun prev-match () (interactive nil) (next-match -1))
(global-set-key [(shift f3)] 'prev-match)
(global-set-key [backtab] 'auto-complete)
;; OCaml configuration
;;  - better error and backtrace matching

(defun set-ocaml-error-regexp ()
  (set
   'compilation-error-regexp-alist
   (list '("[Ff]ile \\(\"\\(.*?\\)\", line \\(-?[0-9]+\\)\\(, characters \\(-?[0-9]+\\)-\\([0-9]+\\)\\)?\\)\\(:\n\\(\\(Warning .*?\\)\\|\\(Error\\)\\):\\)?"
    2 3 (5 . 6) (9 . 11) 1 (8 compilation-message-face)))))

(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'set-ocaml-error-regexp)
(add-hook 'caml-mode-hook 'set-ocaml-error-regexp)
;; ## added by OPAM user-setup for emacs / base ## 56ab50dc8996d2bb95e7856a6eddb17b ## you can edit, but keep this line
(require 'opam-user-setup "~/.emacs.d/opam-user-setup.el")
;; ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for emacs / base ## keep this line
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

- **Versions**

Merlin: 3.7.0

Dune: 2.1.3

Emacs: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian

Opam: 2.0.5

Ocaml: 4.08.1

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my problem in setting-up an "opam switch" into my working directory (WD). Once you are into your WD you have to launch the following command:

```html
opam switch create . ocaml-base-compiler
```

Then, I reinstalled all the needed packages. Utop surprisingly replaced ocaml REPL in emacs ^^' (but i don't mind too much...). Now, dune and merlin "see" the packages.

Nevertheless, this tutorial helped me providing you this answer; https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/quickstart_ocaml_project_dune.html

(Please note that opam, emacs and utop were already installed on my working environment).